# Sending form JSON data to server via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, forms, body-parser

I want to manually send my form data in JSON format to the server.
I changed my form data to a JSON fomat below.
The data I have in my clients-side javascript is in JSON (ie`{"firstname":"john","lastname":"smith"}`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost:3000/UserRegistration",
    dataType: 'application/json',
    data: JSONData,
    success: function(data) {

    }
});
```

I am using body-parser and in my server.js code, I do console.log(req.body) but the data is shown in this format

```
{ '{"firstname":"john","lastname":"smith"}': '' }
```

It added more curly braces. Why is that? How can i access the data in the server side

Comment: instead of `application/json` try `JSON`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just serialize the form and bodyparser will parse it into json for you.

```
$.post('http://localhost:3000/UserRegistration', form.serialize(), function(data) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`dataType: 'application/json'` will expect `json` response from `server`

Set `processData : false` and `contentType : 'application/json'`[[*Ref*](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)]

> **processData:** By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to `false`

---

> **contentType:** When sending data to the server, use this content type. Default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine for most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to $.ajax(), then it is always sent to the server (even if no data is sent)

Answer (score 0):

Please directly parsed your object to json. for example: JSON.Stringfy(obj)

Comment: agree with Rayon too | Set processData : false and contentType : 'application/json'